# How do i put a time into a datetime field

Tags: python, django

I am getting times in the form of eg. 1:00 from a json file and I need to get them into a datetime field. How do I convert this into a datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import datetime, time

t = time.strptime("1:00", "%H:%M")
dt = datetime.datetime(*t[:6])
```